# How to find whether a particular application already exists in iOS through code

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to find whether a particular application already exists in iOS through code

Comment: Do NOT set "Iphone programming" as the title of your questions, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this. You are **restricted** to your application's sandbox and cannot access any other app's data.

Comment: @sneha Not **legally** at least.

Comment: No. This is not allowed and will cause your app to be rejected.